# Java bean definition in application context (Spring)

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Spring IOC, how can I convert this method to a bean definition in application context xml?

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.client.apache.ApacheHttpClient;
import com.sun.jersey.client.apache.config.ApacheHttpClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.client.apache.config.DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig;

public static Client getRestClient() {
    // configuration for jersey client
    ApacheHttpClientConfig config = new DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig();
    Map<String, Object> properties = config.getProperties();
    properties.put(ApacheHttpClientConfig.PROPERTY_CONNECT_TIMEOUT,
            RESTUtil.dispatcherHttpTimeOut);

    // create client
    return ApacheHttpClient.create(config);
}
```

More detail: I want to get an instance of Client from the spring IOC, currently I use this method (getRestClient) to get it, so something like this:

```
<!-- Apache http rest client -->
<bean id="apacheHttpClient" name="Rest Client"
    class="com.sun.jersey.client.apache.ApacheHttpClient" factory-method="create">
    <constructor-arg></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: Not sure what you mean as 'convert method to bean definition'. What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="apacheHttpClient" class="com.sun.jersey.client.apache.ApacheHttpClient" 
         factory-method="getRestClient"/>
```

Seems like you pretty much had it. Was it not working? You just then need to pass this bean as a ref as a property or constructor arg to any class that needs to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you wanted to ask was how to tell Spring to create the bean using a static factory method.

[This thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?56526-Using-factory-beans-with-factory-method-parameters) might help.

`<bean id="restClient" class="com.your.app.ClassWithTheFactoryMethod" factory-method="getRestClient"/>
</bean>`

should work

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I could come to doing *exactly* what you had in your code. I had to refer to the ApacheHttpClientConfig.PROPERTY_CONNECT_TIMEOUT's value literally, and just put in 120 for RESTUtil.dispatcherHttpTimeOut (because I don't know what it is). Note that the "#{120}" expression is needed to pass that value in as an Integer rather than a String, which would cause an exception.

```
<!-- Apache http rest client -->
<bean id="apacheHttpClient" name="Rest Client"
    class="com.sun.jersey.client.apache.ApacheHttpClient" factory-method="create">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.sun.jersey.client.apache.config.DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig">
            <property name="properties['com.sun.jersey.client.property.connectTimeout']" value="#{120}" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```